# Number format exception in scala

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to write a scala program to generate an output file `omega0_Real.txt` which contains pre-calculated values of the cosine function for inputs ranging from 0 to pi/2 radians. Each of these calculated values are  72 bit long and are stored in hex format. The code I have written so far is as follows:

```
import java.io._
import scala.math._

object omega0_Real {
def main (args: Array[String]) {
val arg = (0.0).to(2-pow(2, -10), pow(2, -10))
val cosArg = arg.map (i => cos(i))
val cosBit = cosArg.map (i => List.tabulate(72)(j = (BigDecimal((i*pow(2,j))).toBigInt % 2)))
val cosStr = cosBit.map (i => i mkString)
val cosBig = cosStr.map (i => BigInt(i, 2))
val cosBigStr = cosBig.map (i => i.toString(16))
val cosList = cosBigStr.toList
val file = "omega0_Real.txt"
val writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)))
for (x <- cosList) {
    writer.write(x + "\n")
    }
    writer.close()
}
```

which gives the error: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Illegal embedded sign character` followed by many others. Please help me debug this code. 
PS: I ran this code line-by-line on sbt console but it did not give any error, although the values generated were erroneous.

Comment: It would help if you post the complete output you get when you run your code.

Comment: You are ending up with some lists of ints that have negative numbers.  When you convert those to strings, it includes the negative sign (`-`).  Then when you try and turn that string back into a `BigInt`, it fails on those ones because of the negative signs in the string.

Comment: "val arg = (0.0).to(2-pow(2, -10), pow(2, -10))" isn't the same as "inputs ranging from 0 to pi/2 radians". For the values that are greater than pi/2, the result is negative, which as @cmbaxter says is your problem